# How to organize "able" classes in PHP

Tags: php, oop, interface

I have a namespaced application in PHP and Yii.  I now have a need to implement "orderable.php" and would like to keep these interfaces all in one folder.  I'm unsure what to call this folder.  Any suggestions?  In Java this seems much simpler ^_^

Comment: I fail to see how code organization is not constructive.  Sometimes I wonder about the moderation on this site...

Answer (score 1):

If you have namespaced application, sooner or later you will notice that interfaces also should have have their own namespace, so better follow [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) and put it alongside classes in namespaced directory tree.